# Cannot get querystring in a .NET Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am having a problem getting a querystring in an application I am creating with visual studio 2013 Express.
I call a default.aspx page with a button that has as PostBackUrl "default.aspx?par=insert".

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonCreate" runat="server" Text="Create Field" PostBackUrl="#?par=insert" CommandName="insertXML" OnClick="MyBtnHandler" />
```

In the Page_Load event of default.aspx I simply try to get the querystring value with

```
Request.QueryString["par"]
```

but I do not obtain anything.

I also tried to check the querystring with Request.QueryString.Count and I always get 0.

Is there something that has to do with the RouteConfig file? I am noticing that my url is changed into something more friendly even if this was not required.

Anyway my URL in the address bar shows the querystring and appears like this

```
http://localhost:2844/Default#?par=insert
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing after a # will actually be sent to the server, remove the #.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I changed my postback in many way and at the end I left it with that #, so all my further tests were useless.

I removed it and finally I got my querystring.